# Access system selection colour

Tags: front-end, color, gui-construction

On some operating systems it is possible to customize selection colours and other GUI colours. I have set yellow for mine:

[image]

Is it possible to retrieve this colour in Mathematica, so that it can be used in custom GUI construction?

Comment: On what operating system(s) do you need to do it?

Comment: @MarcoB I somehow managed to phrase the answer while trying to respond to your comment ... posting now.

Comment: Hehe, Socratic method for the win :-) (+1)

Comment: @MarcoB To be accurate, it seems it *might* be possible in 12.0 using `CurrentValue["SystemColors"]`. The documentation is already online, but this can't be expected to work reliably in the cloud (which is the  public way to run 12.0 today)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since version 12.0, this is possible using

```
CurrentValue["SystemColors"]
```

See [`CurrentValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CurrentValue.html) under Details.

On my system I get

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to use this to set these colors?